# Is this the proper use of considering?

Tags: word-usage

I am doing a book review and this does not seem like the proper use of considering in a heading but I cannot explain why. Is this an acceptable use of considering in a heading:

> ***Foundations for considering acquired communication disorders***

Comment: Do you mean **considering** as in "_thinking about_ acquired communication disorders"; or as in "...for thinking communication disorders to be ... [something] ?

Comment: It seems OK to me, with _considering_ being @Margana's first sense. I suspect you interpreted it as the second sense, which needs another clause, and that's why it seemed wrong to you.

Answer (score 3):

There are several uses of the verb *[consider](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/consider)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1.0 Think carefully about (something), typically before making a decision:
>   *each application is considered on its merits*
>   (as adjective
>   considered)
>   *I may not have time to give a considered reply to
>   suggestions*
>
> 1.1 Think about and be drawn towards (a course of action):
>   he had considered giving up his job
>
> 1.2 Believe to be; think:
>   [WITH OBJECT AND INFINITIVE]: *at first women were considered to be at low risk from HIV*
>   [WITH CLAUSE]: *I don’t consider that I’m to blame*
>
> 1.3 [WITH OBJECT AND COMPLEMENT] Regard (someone or something) as having a specified quality:
>   *I consider him irresponsible*
>
> 1.4 Take (something) into account when making a judgement:
>   *one service area is not enough when you consider the number of cars using this
>   motorway*
>
> 2.0 Look attentively at:
>   *the old
>   man considered his granddaughter thoughtfully*
>
> *Oxford Dictionaries Online*

The uses defined in entry 1.2 and 1.3 of Oxford Dictionaries Online would require an extra word or phrase:

> 1.2 *Reasons for **considering** acquired communication disorders [to be a major educational agenda]*
>
> 1.3 *Apology for **considering** [that I was to blame]*

All of the other uses would work as a gerund similar to the example in the OP:

> 1.0 *Foundations for **considering** acquired communication disorders*
>
> 1.1 *Reasons for **considering** a new location*
>
> 1.4 *Factors for **considering** the possible outcomes*
>
> 2.0 *Opportunity for **considering** his sustained gaze*